# how to take string from returned plist array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist

When I am trying to take the value from a plist and append it to an array

```
nameArray.append(namesArray!.objectForKey("Item1")! as! String)
```

The target item is a string but it appears to be inside the plist array, can anyone explain how to get it out please?

The print of namesArray!.objectForKey("Item1")! followed by the error are shown below:

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text. This prevents indexing and other text related operations. After all, It's not difficult to copy and paste text from Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the value of the "Item1" key as an array of Strings, then fetch the first object from the array (since it appears there's only one). And if you like the idea that your app should not crash everytime a value is `nil`, better use `if let` than force-unwrapping everything with `!`.

Example:

```
if let names = namesArray, 
    let items = names.objectForKey("Item1") as? [String], 
    let result = items.first {

    nameArray.append(result)
}
```

Comment: Of course you should avoid force-unwrapping, but it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @imnosov I agree—at least the question implies that the type of deserialized objects is known in advance.

Comment: Ok thanks but there is an array of Strings, i'm basically trying to save some data, and when i'm saving a new presentation, its extracting the array, appending the new item and then re-saving the array to a plist

Answer (score 0):

Just take the first element of your array:

```
nameArray.append((namesArray!.objectForKey("Item1")! as! [String])[0])
```